# Converting access file from sendmail to postfix

Tags: postfix, sendmail

I'm looking to convert a two-decade-old highly-configured sendmail installation (currently running on AlmaLinux 9) into postfix. Among the conversions is adapting the existing `/etc/mail/access` file to `/etc/postfix/access`.

Some of the statements look like they can just be copied over directly, though please confirm this if you can:

```
# by default we allow relaying from localhost...
Connect:127.0.0.1               RELAY

# Allow systems on our DMZ to use this server.
Connect:123.44.55               RELAY

# Allow systems on our NAT network to use this server as well.
Connect:10.44                   RELAY

# Accept mail sent to our  domain.
To:company.example.com          OK

# Forward any mail sent to our mailing-list server.
mailinglist.company.example.com     RELAY

# Reject commonly-used non-existent addresses
From:document@company.example.com   ERROR:5.7.1:550 Fake source address
From:staff@example.com              ERROR:5.7.1:550 Fake source address
From:noreply@example.com            ERROR:5.7.1:550 Fake source address
From:support@example.com            ERROR:5.7.1:550 Fake source address

# 28-Nov-2005: Too much spam is being relayed by these guys, and bounced to us.
Connect:66.155.233.70               ERROR:5.7.1:550 Your mail server is a spam relay

# 09-Jun-2016: Uber-bad domain list. There are almost no servers in these domains that do
# not send spam. 
accountants                     ERROR:5.7.1:550 Domain used to send spam
bid                             ERROR:5.7.1:550 Domain used to send spam

# 09-Jun-2016: We've got a problem: When an unknown user receives
# email on our mail server, our mail server will reject mail
# to these users with "DSN: User unknown". This sounds fine, except
# that for aliases it sends a new email with that message back to the server
# that sent it. This results in "backscatter": our mail server starts
# sending mail from spammers back to bogus servers or forged
# addresses. The following is a list of user names completely retired
# from our mail server. It may not solve this problem, but it will
# hopefully reduce it. 

To:aaron@                    ERROR:550 No such user 
To:betsy@                    ERROR:550 No such user
```

Where I'm having difficulty: Sendmail allows me to set mail delays and connection throttles on a per-system or per-domain basis. I've searched the postfix documentation, but I don't see how do this.

To be specific, if I include the following statements in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`:

```
FEATURE(`greet_pause', `500')  dnl 
FEATURE(`ratecontrol', `nodelay', `terminate') dnl
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE',`200') dnl
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_WINDOW_SIZE',`60s') dnl
FEATURE(`conncontrol', `nodelay', `terminate') dnl
```

Then in `/etc/mail/access`, I can include statements like:

```
GreetPause:batchmanager.company.example.com    400
GreetPause:company.example.com   0
GreetPause:mailinglist.company.example.com  0
GreetPause:127.0.0.1            0
GreetPause:friend.other.com     20
GreetPause:friendly.other.gov   20
GreetPause:10.44                0

ClientRate:123.44.55.66         6000    # mailinglist
ClientRate:123.44.55.77         60      # batchmanager
ClientRate:127.0.0.1            0
ClientRate:123.44.55            60

ClientConn:123.44.55.77         5       # batchmanager
ClientConn:123.44.55.66       500       # mailinglist
```

Then there are remote sites that appear to have problems with their TLS configuration. Or maybe it's us that has a problem, but only these sites choose to detect and reject it. I work around this in `/etc/mail/access`:

```
Try_TLS:yetanother.different.com NO
```

I've RTFM'ed, but with no luck. Any ideas on how to implement these features in postfix?

Comment: I think (without testing yet) that I have the answer to my last question. I'll answer it in this comment, just in case someone is searching for it. I'll put it in a formal "answer" once I've verified it. 

Create a file `/etc/postfix/tls_per_site` with lines like: `yetanother.different.com.    NONE`

In `/etc/postfix/mail.cf`, include the line:`smtp_tls_per_site = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_per_site`

Then use the commands: `cd /etc/postfix; postmap tls_per_site; postfix reload`

Comment: I'm continuing to work on this, but I can confirm: None of the `/etc/mail/access` lines can simply be "copied into postfix" directly. It's more involved than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, and cursing the fate of everyone who ever told me that postfix was easier to configure than sendmail, I think I have the answers to my own questions.

Note that I have not had a chance to test if the restrictions work. I've implemented the code, there are no error messages, and my test configuration works. However, I won't be able to fully test the anti-spam code until I put the configuration into production and the full weight of the internet comes down upon the server.

The short version: postfix does not support placing all the potential statements in sendmail's `/etc/mail/access` into a single file. Rather, the functions have to split up into different files associated with [various statements](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) in postfix's `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Another note: I placed most of these new external files into hash tables. This was mainly because it wasn't clear from the postfix documentation whether plain text files could be used in some of the following `main.cf` statements, but hash tables always could. Wherever you see an option below like `hash:/etc/postfix/my-table`, it means that I created `/etc/postfix/my-table` then executed:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/my-table
postfix reload
```

I'm not sure if `postfix reload` was always needed, but I played it safe.

**Relays**

In the original `/etc/mail/access`, I had:

```
Connect:127.0.0.1                   RELAY
Connect:123.44.55                   RELAY
Connect:10.44                       RELAY
mailinglist.company.example.com     RELAY
```

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, I put:

```
mynetworks = 123.44.55.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8, 10.44.0.0/16
mydomain = company.example.com
mydestination = $myhostname,
       localhost.$mydomain,
       localhost,
       $mydomain,
       hash:/etc/postfix/local-host-names
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unauth_destination
relay_domains = $mydestination, hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
```

In `/etc/postfix/relay_recipients`, I put:

```
mailinglist.company.example.com     RELAY
```

In `/etc/postfix/local-host-names` I have various alternative names for our mail server as defined by CNAMEs in our DNS records, just in case:

```
mail.company.example.com
smtp.company.example.com
```

**Rejecting "From" address**

In my original `access` files, I had:

```
From:document@company.example.com   ERROR:5.7.1:550 Fake source address
From:staff@example.com              ERROR:5.7.1:550 Fake source address
From:noreply@example.com            ERROR:5.7.1:550 Fake source address
From:support@example.com            ERROR:5.7.1:550 Fake source address

accountants                     ERROR:5.7.1:550 Domain used to send spam
bid                             ERROR:5.7.1:550 Domain used to send spam
```

In `main.cf`, I have:

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
  check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/from_restrictions
```

where `/etc/postfix/from_restrictions` contains:

```
document@company.example.com   550 Fake source address typical of viruses
staff@example.com              550 Fake source address typical of viruses
noreply@example.com            550 Fake source address typical of viruses
support@example.com            550 Fake source address typical of viruses

accountants                    550 Domain used to send spam
bid                            550 Domain used to send spam
```

Will the lines that reject the TLDs in `/etc/mail/access` work in postfix? The [postfix access man page](https://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) is a bit ambiguous. I'll see what happens.

**Rejecting "To" address**

In `access` I had:

```
To:aaron@                    550 No such user 
To:betsy@                    550 No such user
```

In `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  permit_mynetworks,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10040,
  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/to_restrictions
```

with `etc/postfix/to_restrictions` containing:

```
aaron@                    550 No such user 
betsy@                    550 No such user
```

The `check_policy_service` has to do with postfwd; I'll mention that below.

**Connection rates and number of connections**

Postfix doesn't let you set simple per-IP or per-domain values for these parameters, the way one can in `/etc/mail/access`:

```
ClientRate:123.44.55.66         6000    # mailinglist
ClientRate:123.44.55.77         60      # batchmanager
ClientRate:127.0.0.1            0
ClientRate:123.44.55            60

ClientConn:123.44.55.77         5       # batchmanager
ClientConn:123.44.55.66       500       # mailinglist
```

What I did instead is set overall limits for most connections, then defined exceptions in `main.cf`:

```
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
smtpd_client_auth_rate_limit = 60
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 50
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 100
smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions =
   $mynetworks,
   4.56.78.0/24,   # friend.other.com
   5.67.89.0/24.   # friendly.other.gov
```

This is close, but not exactly what I'd want. In particular, the machine I called `batchmanager.company.example.com` can start generating thousands of emails if a user carelessly submits a cluster of jobs that each start generating emails reporting the errors. With sendmail, I could throttle that at the mail server. I decided to try to do it with [postfwd](http://postfwd.org/doc.html).

I finally left `/etc/postfwd/postfwd.cf` with:

```
id=RATE_UNKNOWN
   client_name==unknown
   action=rate(client_address/3/300/450 4.7.1 Deferred, max 3 requests in 5 mins from $$client_name at $$client_address)

id=THROTTLE_BATCH
   sender_localpart==batchmanager
   action=rate(client_address/20/60/450 4.7.1 Deferred, max 20 emails per minute from $$sender)

id=DEFAULT; action=DUNNO
```

This also restricts those spammers without client names, but that doesn't mean much these days.

**GreetPause**

There's no direct equivalent of this in postfix. My half-baked solution is to introduce a delay for systems that I don't recognize. In `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/friendly_sites,
  reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
  sleep 1,
  reject_unauth_pipelining
```

where `/etc/postfix/friendly_sites` contains:

```
friend.other.com     OK
friendly.other.gov   OK
```

I got the impression that I might be able to introduce an optional delay using [postscreen](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/configure-postscreen-in-postfix-to-block-spambots), but I did not see a way to do it. I included these lines in `main.cf`:

```
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
```

In `cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr`:

```
123.44.55.66/32  permit    # mail server IP address
```

At best, that just gets rid of some forms of spammer attacks, but doesn't create any delays.

**Turn off TLS for some sites**

As I noted in a comment, I could do that in postfix. In `/etc/mail/access` I had the line:

```
Try_TLS:yetanother.different.com   NO
```

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, I have:

```
smtp_tls_per_site = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_per_site
```

In `/etc/postfix/tls_per_site`, I have:

```
yetanother.different.com   NONE
```

**Wrap up**

I recognize that I could be overlapping anti-spam functionality in some of the above. I decided I'd rather be safe than sorry. If you can spot any problems with my conversion, please let me know.